# What does it mean for a level curve to be closed or open?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

So, I understand what it means to be closed/open or bounded/unbounded in terms of domain.

What about level curves? For example, for $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 = c$, is this closed/open or bounded/unbounded?

I thought these terms refer to a region, not a line or curve.

How could we determine if a level curve is open or closed and boudned/unbounded?

Comment: It may refer to the solution set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2 - y^2 = c\}$ i.e. the points on which $f$ vanishes

Answer (score 0):

A **closed curve** is by definition a continuous image of a circle.  This is not the same meaning of closed as in "closed set". In particular a closed curve is bounded.
A level curve $f(x,y) = c$ of a smooth, nowhere constant function, if it is bounded, typically consists of one or more closed curves.

A sufficient condition for $f(x,y) = c$ to be bounded is that $|f(x,y)| \to \infty$ as $|x| + |y| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The level curve is a subset of the domain. It's perhaps not what you would typically consider a "region" since it does not have the same dimension as the domain, but the definitions of being an open or closed set (every point is an interior point; contains all of its limit point) can still be applied. For your function $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ it's clear that all of the level sets are closed and not open; in fact it can be proven that the level sets of all continuous functions are closed (this is sometimes used as the *definition* of a continuous function).

I don't know that there's an easy test for whether a given function's level curve is bounded, other than a case-by-case analysis. There are some sufficient conditions which guarantee that all level curves will be bounded; for example, if the function is strictly convex.