# Necessary and/or sufficient conditions for polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ to have a bounded isosurface

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, surfaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial. What are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions, preferably on the polynomial coefficients, for a given isosurface of $f$ to be bounded?

Based on post [What does it mean for a level curve to be closed or open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614165) I conjecture that one example of a sufficient condition is $|f(x,y,z)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|x|+|y|+|z|\rightarrow\infty$ but I am not sure if this is equivalent to some other condition related to the polynomial coefficients.

If the mentioned sufficient condition holds, does it hold for all isosurfaces of $f$?

On a related note, what are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for an isosurface of $f$ to consist of a single connected component?

Comment: Your criterion is equivalent to determining that $f$ is proper.

Comment: Then, if one isosurface of $f$ is bounded, all other isosurfaces of $f$ are bounded as well?

Comment: I haven't thought about that issue. I was reinterpreting your "conjecture" (i.e., Robert Israel's condition) in terms of a common topological condition.

Comment: What is the meaning of notation $|f(x,y,z)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|x|+|y|+|z|\rightarrow\infty$?