# Meaning of notation $\lim_{|x|+|y|\rightarrow\infty}|f(x,y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation, soft-question

I recently stumbled upon the statement "$|f(x,y)|\rightarrow\infty$ as $|x|+|y|\rightarrow\infty$" in Robert Israel's answer at [What does it mean for a level curve to be closed or open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614165/what-does-it-mean-for-a-level-curve-to-be-closed-or-open).

What does this notation mean? I think it is equivalent to the following condition:

For any curve, not necessarily a level curve, $C:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ where $C(t):=(x(t),y(t))$, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}(|x(t)|+|y(t)|) = \infty$.

In general, given $g,h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, when does the notation $\lim_{g(x,y)\rightarrow\infty}h(x,y)$ make sense?

Comment: The statement in Robert Israel's answer  is actually "$|f(x,y)| \to \infty$ as $|x| + |y| \to \infty$, which is a different matter

Comment: Are you comfortable with the formal, $\varepsilon, \delta$ (or $M, N$) definition of the limit?

Comment: @HansEngler You're right. I made a mistake in my post. I have edited the question to make this correction.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, $$\lim_{g(x,y) \to \infty} h(x,y) = \infty$$ means

> For any real M, there is some N such that [for any $x,y$,] $g(x,y) > N$ implies $h(x,y) > M$.

In the equivalent contrapositive, this is

> For any real M, there is some N such that [for any $x,y$,] $h(x,y) \leq M$ implies $g(x,y) \leq N$.

---

Using this form, the point of Robert's comment can be made more clear: Consider the level curve $f(x,y) = c$ and suppose the limit in Robert's post is true.  By setting $M=|c|+1$, we conclude there is some $N$ such $|f(x,y)| \leq |c|+1$ implies $|x|+|y| \leq N$.  In particular, on the whole of the level curve $f(x,y) = c$, we have $|x| + |y| \leq N$, which is bounded (it's a square along with its interior), so the level curve $f(x,y) = c$ is bounded for each $c$.

Comment: In particular, it has nothing at all to do with the parametrization of a particular level curve.